# Gatsby Server Rendering APIs and ssr in next js are they the same?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, gatsby

I have just learned to use Gatsby Js to build an ecommerce website. I plan to use the SSR method on my website. and now I'm considering Gatsby and Next for developing my website. just in case if one day the web enlarges technology if users are increasing. and so there is no technology transfer that is too large if one day the web app user is getting bigger. and which one should I choose? Is ssr Gatsby or ssr Next?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand the different between two approaches.
With NextJS, whenever user enter your site by a link, NextJS will generate static content (HTML, CSS, JS) by every requests. You need to setup backend, web server and so on to make your site run.

On the other hand, with Gatsby, It generates ALL pages, ALL static content by the time you run "build" command, that makes you deploy all of above static files become easier.

A gatsby blog to introduce about Gatsby cloud to make the Gatsby build process faster because their approach make build process so long.
But if your site has less than 1000 pages, it's okay to go with Gastby, better UX and DX.

Comment: In fact, Next.js also does static site generation, which can be run standalone without the need of a Node.js server.

Comment: Yes correct. The ouput are only static files, so easy to deploy to CDN.